# Encrypt and decrypt the database before moving it

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i want to encrypt the database file before deattach it to move it to another sql server and decrypt the database file on the other sql server

Comment: and what's your question exactly?

Comment: [**`This Link May Help You`**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965861/encrypt-decrypt-existing-database-using-sqlcipher-in-android)

Comment: i want by database encrypted before moving it on a dvd to another computer and i want to decrypt it on the distination computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try protecting your archive instead of DB cypher mechanics. File-protectors are much more mature today. Usually, simple 7z-archive with a password on it is a quite fine precaution to sleep well in the middle of your DB migration.

You can encapsulate 7zip LZMA into your code like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449998/free-compression-library-for-c-sharp-which-supports-7zip-lzma) for C#.

I advice you a highly available solution concerning that we discuss a small businees solution. For Enterprise business, it's all different completely.

The other option is using native SQL Server Encryption. Then you should follow the [genuine manual here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278098(v=sql.100).aspx)

`CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION` and etc...

Comment: could you explain more

Comment: You need to detach your db and backup it then in a number of files (.mdf, etc). And these files you need to encrypt with 7zip archiver. [Here is the instruction](http://www.northeastern.edu/securenu/?page_id=2573). Then copy encrypted archive to any media drive, unpack the archive with your key or password (according to encryption method) and Attach your db to new SQL Server instance.

Comment: thanks for your reply it is a wonderful way but i want to do the encryption through my program then deattach db files by my program as the user will just take the files and put them on dvd. the user cannot do any more operations

Comment: Modified my initial answer according to your remarks